# Laravel 5.8 Routed page not found 404 error

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. I am learning Laravel from tutorial and I drive into one problem which I can't solve.
**I think I have problem somewhere into Routing, but I can't find it**
Funny thing is that if the `href` is `{{route('tag.create'}}`, then it goes to creating page, but when I need to use ID it's not working... 
I had same functionality for posts and categories, but everything worked fine for those two. So I really need your help to see what I can't see. I have these files:

`index.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <th>
                        Tag name
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        Delete
                    </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @if($tags->count()>0)
                        @foreach($tags as $tag)
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{$tag->tag}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{route('tag.delete', ['id' =>$tag->id])}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    @else
                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="5" class="text-center">
                                No tags yet
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    @endif
                </tbody>
            </table>    

        </div>
    </div>


@stop
```

`web.php` - this is the place where I define routes for tags for `TagsController.php`:

```
//Tags
    Route::get('/tags',[
        'uses'=>'TagsController@index',
        'as'=> 'tags'
    ]);

    Route::post('/tag/update/{$id}',[
        'uses'=>'TagsController@update',
        'as'=> 'tag.update'
    ]);

    Route::get('/tag/create',[
        'uses'=>'TagsController@create',
        'as'=> 'tag.create'
    ]);
    Route::post('/tag/store',[
        'uses'=>'TagsController@store',
        'as'=> 'tag.store'
    ]);
    Route::get('/tag/delete/{$id}',[
        'uses'=>'TagsController@destroy',
        'as'=> 'tag.delete'
    ]);
```

`TagsController.php` - at first I tried to destroy the element, then I tried to return create view(because when I go through /tag/create rout everything works), but neither worked here

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        return view ('admin.tags.create');
        /*
        Tag::destroy($id);

        Session::flash('success', 'Tag deleted succesfully');

        return redirect()->back();*/
    }
```

Comment: Change `{$id}` to `{id}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should set the route to  `Route::get('/tag/delete/{id}',[ 'uses'=>'TagsController@destroy', 'as'=> 'tag.delete' ]);`   because in your case you are telling the route to expect a variable called  `$id`

Comment: Thanks mate. Hate myself for that I didn't see $ before ID.

Comment: Anytime mate. Don't beat yourself over it these things happen alot. We forget and add useless $. Make sure you change it in the update too. Good luck and if you want please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please change the parameters in the route setup in web.php from $id to id. I should solve your issue.

Eg: `Route::get('/tag/delete/{id}',[
        'uses'=>'TagsController@destroy',
        'as'=> 'tag.delete'
    ]);`

Thanks !!.